# How to manipulate results from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following query that I've been using, but everytime I have to rename a few things to be in order. Don't know how could I apply replace or regex_replace..

For example, with the query below, I get something like:

Row orderTotal  partners    data
1   100         partner_b   01/01/2021

And I end up needing to rename "partner_b" to Partner B

```
    EXTRACT (date from CreationDateBR) as data,
    FROM XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    WHERE CreationDateBR BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-01-01'
    AND loja IN ('Marketplace A')
    AND parceiros NOT IN ('partner_a','partner_c')
GROUP BY partners,data
ORDER BY data,partners asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [INITCAP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions.md#initcap) function

for example

```
with data as (
  select 'partner_b' partner union all 
  select 'partner_c' union all 
  select 'partner d'
)
select partner, initcap(partner)
from data
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: I think in my attempt to hide the tru name a direct the request to a different approach.

Not always it will be the same name, sometimes I need rename: "partner_a" to "actual alias name".

Also, how can I integrate the suggestion into my existing query? (I did not create the original one).